# SoapUI JsonPath Existence Path always true with arrays

Tags: soapui, jsonpath

I have the following response:

```
[
  {
    "name": "aaa",
    "status": "UP"
  },
  {
    "name": "bbb",
    "status": "DOWN"
  }
]
```

I want to assert that there is at least one element with name "aaa".
JsonPath Count works fine:

```
$[?(@.name=='aaa')]
```

Returns 1, and

```
$[?(@.name=='ccc')]
```

or

```
$[?(@.asdkasj=='aaa')]
```

Returns 0.

However, I want to assert that at least one exists, so I'm trying to use JsonPath Existence Path, but all of these return true.

```
$[?(@.name=='ccc')]
$[?(@.asdsad=='asdasd')]
$[?(@.name=='aaa')]
```

[image: Screenshot]

Why does it always return true?

Should I use a script to make this assertion?

SoapUI version: 5.4.0

Build Date: 20171204-0633

Comment: For me `$[?(@.asdsad=='asdasd')]` and `$[?(@.name=='ccc')]` are both returning false and `$[?(@.name=='aaa')]` is returning true in the existence match assertion. Do you have a screen shot where they're all returning true?

Comment: @craigcaulfield I've updated the question with a screenshot and SoapUI version

Comment: In the Expected Result field of the dialog, do you have `true` or `false` or something else? If it's `false`, then that's good: the JSONPath hasn't found a match in your document and the test was successful.

Comment: It always returns true. If I expect `false`,  the message is "expecting [false], actual was [true]"

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get the same result as your dialog was to have `false` as the `Expected Result`:

[image: jsonpath]

Which to me looks like a valid test: you're testing for `$[?(@.asdsad=='asdasd')]`, and not finding it. Is your `Expected Result` the same?

Comment: Clearly we don't have the same behavior. If I expect `false` like in your screenshot, the message is "expecting [false], actual was [true]". The evaluation of the expression always return true. This wrong behavior only happens with "Existence Path". Count and match work as expected. Which version are you using?

Comment: OK: works in Ready API 2.3 (soapUI Pro) but fails in soapUI 5.4. Comparing the JSON libraries in the two installations, those in soapUI 5.4 are significantly behind, for example `json-path-0.9.1` to `json-path-2.4.0`, and who knows what else. So, I think it's safe to say the JSONPath Existence assertion in soapUI 5.4 is unreliable. You could raise a bug with SmartBear or just go with your original alternative.